# Swagger UI erases Parameters

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

The error that I'm seeing is that as soon as I enter something into a Parameter on the UI it disappears.[image: What the UI looks like]

I am creating Controllers on the fly based on method decorations, so I can't create the XML that drives swagger.json at build-time. As a way around it, I created another controller which inspects the controllers that were added to the runtime and outputs valid swagger.json (or so I think). This works okay with POST, but seems fails peculiarly when trying to add route parameters to GET.

This is the json I generate for my GET:

```
"openapi": "3.0.1",

  ... // cutting out unrelated other stuff

            "/api/v1/test4/{Value2}": {
               "get": {
                  "tags": [
                     ],
                  "summary": "A sample GET",
                  "parameters": [


         {
            "name": "Value2",
            "in ": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": ""
            }
         },
,
                  ],
                  "responses": {
                     "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "content": {
                           "application/json": {
                                 "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TestReply"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
         }
```

The project is a .Net Framework 4.8 one, and the packages I'm using are Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.2.0 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.5.1.

Comment: I should add that I've seen: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4269 and checked the code, but although that is exactly my symptom, it doesn't seem to be my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extra space in the name of the `in` attribute:

```
"in ": "path",
   ^
   ^
```

Remove that space.

You can also use https://editor.swagger.io to check your API definition for syntax errors.